# At which version an odoo introduced ORM API?And need a difference between with and without ORM API.Could anyone explain me please?

Tags: odoo-8

I'm new to odoo(openerp),so facing difficulty to understand the concepts in odoo.Now I started to learn newly about ORM API.From that I arose a question like at which version an odoo introduced ORM API?And to know the difference between with and without ORM API.I searched through many website but I could'nt get the correct answers.So I came over here to get the perfect answer.Could anyone will explain me?